# Гугл формы: можно ли в одном вопросе сделать разные созависимые типы ответов?

Tags: html, css, form, google-forms

Есть такой пример формы: варианты ответов - чекбоксы, но при выборе некоторых появляются дополнительные поля (текстовые, файловые и т.д.). Можно ли такое реализовать на Гугл-формах? Если да, то каким образом? Ответа в самом Гугле не нашёл.

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
[type="text"],
[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
.open-text:checked ~ [type="text"],
.open-file:checked ~ [type="file"]{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="open-text"> Хочу сообщить о:
    <input type="text" placeholder="Текст вашего сообщения">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="open-file"> Хочу поделиться:
    <input type="file">
  </label>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```